# Update input ng-model after setting the value of Jquery

Tags: angularjs

I had datepicker using jquery. It works when the page is loaded because i set the default date in my controller. Picking a date is ok but the problem is when you get the value using angular js its not updated, always the default value. Anyone how to update the value when date is selected and set by jquery. Really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

html

```
<input type="text" id="date1"  name="date1" ng-model="data.date1">
<input type="text" id="date2"  name="date2" ng-model="data.date2">
<button type="button" ng-click="get()">Test Value</button>
```

jquery

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
language: 'en',
autoClose:true,
dateFormat: 'd MM yyyy',
onSelect: function (fd, date, picker) {
}});

$('#date2').datepicker({
language: 'en',
autoClose:true,
dateFormat: 'd MM yyyy',
onSelect: function (fd, date, picker) {


}});
```

angular js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.data = {};

 // default date
 $scope.data.date1  = new Date();
 $scope.data.date2  = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'days');

 $scope.get = function(){
    console.log($scope.data.date1);
    console.log($scope.data.date2);
 }});
```

Comment: better not to use jquery with angular. You will get different plugins for datepicker in angular itself.

Comment: use angular daptepicker. https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicke

Comment: Thanks for the advice and links.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: Thanks @VipulSolanki. I would try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are about to use `datepicker` more than one time, I suggest to create directive and just use it.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                    onSelect:function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="date1" datepicker />
<input type="text" ng-model="date2" datepicker />
```

For more detail, just check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBOgYzln7G9JG7CRn2KR?p=preview)

Comment: i used this plugin http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/. not working on this plugin. thanks.

Comment: Just check this [documentation](https://github.com/think2011/ng-air-datepicker) for same functionality but with AngularJS. So no need to code into JQuery.

Comment: @Rye You check above given link if you want to continue with your datepicker plugin.